# Create a dictionary from a list of lists with certain criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
l1=[['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2'],['c1','a1']]
```

I want a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{"start":"a1","end":"ä2"},
 {"start":"a2","end":"a3"},
 {"start":"a3","end":"a1"},
 {"start":"b1","end":"b2"},
 {"start":"c1","end":"a1"}
]
```

I have tried the following code and got index out of bounds exception:

```
for val in list_listedges:
    for i in range(0,len(val)):
        dict_edges["start"]=val[i]
        dict_edges["end"]=val[i+1]
```

I am looking for a working solution or enhancement of the above code which would yield the same result.Also, 3 is not a fixed number.It could be 4 or 5 also.In that case,I need all the elements to pair up with each other

Comment: When `i` is the last index, `val[i+1]` is outside the list.

Comment: What would be `i` at the very last iteration? And what `i+1` is going to be at the same time?

Comment: Since you want it to wrap around, use `(i+1)%len(val)`

Comment: yes I sorted that out just now.How could I make it better then?

Comment: But you're also not creating a list of dicts, you're overwriting the same dict each time.

Comment: @Barmar Could you propose a solution to make it clear?

Comment: @ThomasSablik It is just a2 .

Comment: Why don't the lists with only 2 elements wrap around like the ones with 3 elements?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely avoid indexing by using the [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function to generate all the possible pairings of the points in each sublist as illustrated below:

```
from itertools import combinations


l1 = [['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1','b2'], ['c1','a1']]

dicts = [{'start': start, 'end': end}
            for points in l1
                for start, end in combinations(points, 2)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dicts, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'start': 'a1', 'end': 'a2'},
 {'start': 'a1', 'end': 'a3'},
 {'start': 'a2', 'end': 'a3'},
 {'start': 'b1', 'end': 'b2'},
 {'start': 'c1', 'end': 'a1'}]
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I have 5 or 4 elements in a list.For example,If I have a list in the list like [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5].The output I get is [{a1,a2},{a2,a3},{a3,a4},{a4,a5},{a5,a1}] but I also need the other connections like [{a1,a3},{a1,a4},{a2,a5},{a2,a5},{a3,a5}].These values are missing @martineau .I need all the values to be paired up

Comment: Sam: Oh, OK, now I understand what you want — see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. `val[i+1]` won't wrap around to the beginning, use `val[(i+1) % len(val)]`
2. You're overwriting the same dict each time, not appending to a list of dicts.

```
result = []
for val in list_edges:
    for i, start in enumerate(val, 1):
        result.append({"start": start, "end": val[i % len(val)]})
```

Instead of looping over the range, I use `enumerate()` to get the indexes along with the list elements, and specify a starting index of `1` to add 1 automatically.

This doesn't produce precisely the same result as you show. It will also put `{"start": "b2", "end": "b1"}` and `{"start": "a1", "end": "c1"}` in the resulting list, since it wraps all the lists back to the beginning. If 2-element lists should be treated differently, you can add a special check for that in the code.

Comment: It doesn't work if I have 5 or 4 elements in a list.For example,If I have a list in the list like [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5].The output I get is [{a1,a2},{a2,a3},{a3,a4},{a4,a5},{a5,a1}] but I also need the other connections like [{a1,a3},{a1,a4},{a2,a5},{a2,a5},{a3,a5}].These values are missing

Comment: Your code just pairs `i` and `i+1`. Where does the question say that you need all combinations?

Comment: Try using `itertools.combinations()`.

Comment: Could you edit the code to get the proposed solution? @Barmar

Comment: I answered the question you wrote. This sounds like a different question. I pointed you to the tool you need, try to solve it yourself, and if you can't get it to work I'll help.

Comment: I tried it but all I get is a list of tuples.I need a list of dicts @Barmar

Comment: That's just the starting point, you still need to turn each tuple into a dict, but that's easy, isn't it?

Comment: it doesn't work even then

Answer (score 0):

you sure that it's not an IndentationError? the for loops are indented after `list_listedges`, which isn't proper syntax, anyway,  here's how i would do it:

```py
# just a function for the for loop in the next function, ignore it, though it is fine if you copy it :)
def weave(val1, val2): # unneeded for use but u can use this in other scripts, too
  if len(val1) != len(val2):
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("length of value 1 and value 2 are not the same, must be the same\n\n[your OS]: FIX IT OR ELSE SATAN WILL INVITE YOU TO HELL PERSONALLY!!!\n\n(BTW your gf is cheating on you, she is going out with me)\n\n[REPL]: ")
    sys.exit(256)

  w = [] # the returned value
  for i, x in enumerate(val2):
    w += [(val1[i], x)]
  return w

# pay attention to THIS:
def listToDict(LIST, *indexers):
 DICT = {}
 for i, a in weave(LIST, indexers):
  DICT = {**DICT, a: i}
 return DICT

print(weave([1, 3, 7, 5], ["1", "3", "7", "5"]))
print(listToDict([1, 3, 7, 5], "1", "3", "7", "5"))
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question